# Unity blue sprite always showing on top regardless of order

Tags: unity

I have 3 `SpriteRenderer`

1. SpriteRenderer - Green Sprite
2. SpriteRenderer - Blue Sprite
3. SpriteRenderer - Brown Sprite

The problem is that the blue sprite always shows on top of the others. I even tried to keep the `SpriteRenderer` in the same order and change the images but no matter which `SpriteRenderer` I put the blue image into it always shows on top.

I have the sorting layer set to 0 for all 3 and I cannot change them because I will have to change so many other objects in the game.

Comment: Can you walk us through the complete steps we need to reproduce this problem in a new empty project? (Including the 3D positions of the sprite renderer objects, the materials used, etc.)

Comment: You say you can’t change the sorting layer. Can you change the sort order within the layer?

Comment: If the sorting layer and order is same for all of the SpriteRenderer  then last created SpriteRenderer will show on the top of the all SpriteRenderers. In your case last created SpriteRenderer is blue so it shows up on top. So to over come this you need to re create new SpriteRenderer assign image you want. I've tested this and the result is above. I don't know why is this but that's the thing i have experienced. If it is help full then i will put this in the answer. by the way to resolved this which I usually do is to use sorting layers and layer sorting order.

Comment: But at the about statement is not correct if i move the SpriteRenderer over other. Any way its strange overall. So i was not able to assume anything which might clarify the question. But now i am curious why is this :). But i do some more experiments with this if i got any thing useful then i share it here.

Comment: you can change order in sprite renderer. then z axis of sprite and also their order in hierarchi